ETH tokens sent to BNB address in Safe Wallet
Some ETH tokens have been sent to a BNB safe address in Safe Wallet. To recover them I have followed this procedure: https://share.zight.com/z8uBKZYr.
The wallet owner of the Safe Wallet is: 0xa4EcDF16CCc112AD4EBAeAC08Bf250268168689b
The BNB Safe Wallet to which ETH have been sent is: 0x886220E916f6614a10C99a9b3c41ac9c696B7065
Even if I followed the procedure, I don’t see any new ETH address on Safe Wallet when I connect my wallet owner 0xa4EcDF16CCc112AD4EBAeAC08Bf250268168689b.
Please advice how to recover the ETH sent and visible here: https://etherscan.io/address/0x886220e916f6614a10c99a9b3c41ac9c696b7065
